# problem modifying a name property in a React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, properties, this

I am trying to change the name of a component but my logic is all in the parent component and therefore cannot access `this.props.name`.

Here is my start button

```
class StartButton extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.name}</button>
      )
    }
  }
```

Within my `Header` class I am using StartButton with a `name='Start Button'`

```
  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <div className="headerContainer">
            <div id="countdown">
              <p>Countdown: <span id="countdownSpan"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-item-header">
              <StartButton 
                  name='Start Button'.   <------------------------------
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
              />            
              </div>
            <div>
                <p>Word Count: <span id="noOfWords"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the logic I want to use and need this in `Header` class because it is activated by `onClick`.

```
  changeToRestartText = () => {
    this.name = 'Restart Game'; <---------------------------
  }
```

I know, this.name doesn't work, but I am not sure how to access `name='Start Button'` and change its value. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking to change the prop like that (there is no such a way) you should try to use the state for that. Though there are other ways, I'm giving the naive example below. Keep a state, and according to it pass your prop.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    restart: false
  };

  changeToRestartText = () => {
    this.setState({ restart: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { restart } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <StartButton
          name={!restart ? "Start Button" : "Restart Game"}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
        />
        <button onClick={this.changeToRestartText}>Change to restart</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class StartButton extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.name}</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: omg thank you so much. This makes perfect sense. I appreciate the help!